# How much should a (light) punching bag swing?

Tags: boxing

Novice question on boxing a punching bag.

How much should a bag swing when you punch it? This is a light bag (~20kg), suspended from the ceiling.

I've been told to whip punches, not push them, so that the bag isn't pushed too much. But most demonstrations are on a heavy bag; is it possible to have the light bag relatively stationary after maybe a round (3 min) of boxing?

Personally I enjoy hitting the swinging bag because a moving target seems fun, but I'm concerned it may build wrong technique, because I notice light wrist pain when throwing non-straight punches sometimes.

Comment: For what it's worth I agree with you that a moving target is fun, and it also builds a different type of technique, since real targets aren't stationary.  But, regarding the wrist pain, that indicates your technique needs some more work in the accuracy department, which you should work on, on a stationary target. In short: speed, accuracy, power are important and you should train each independently, focused on the specific aspect you are trying to improve at that time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pay attention to these separately. Thanks for breaking it down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a light punching bag, so it will swing. Probably a lot. But there is a reason for the bag to move. That way you can practice movement at the same time. It's more like a real fight this way. If you don't want the bag to move, you might as well hit the wall with gloves on (did it, good for learning the right distance).

If the bag didn't swing (Strapped by top and bottom), you could get your wrists injured (like if you hit a wall). My coach told me that if you want to work on your technique, you should use a mirror, and do some shadow fighting. A punching bag is good for working on your conditioning, and technique together. If you hit strong - You're building condition. If you hit with less force - You're working on your technique.

Also you can just punch with less force. That's going to make the bag swing less. But again - If it's a light bag it will always swing.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to hear that it will swing, I was wondering if I'm doing something very wrong. Time to work on accuracy now. :)

Comment: Accuracy, timing, and rhythm. These will help. They develop like everything else in combat. By practice ;)